# how to allow upto 3 spaces in a string using javascript regular expression

Tags: javascript

Ho to allow upto three blank spaces in a string using java script regular expression

I tried with the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mainStr = "Hello World";
var pattern= /^(?=[^ ]* ?[^ ]*(?: [^ ]*)?$)(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?=[^']*'?[^']*$)[a-zA-Z '-]*$/; 
if(pattern.test(mainStr)){
 alert("matched");
}else{
 alert("not matched");

}
</script>
```

Comment: Note the space can occur anywhere in the string

Comment: Note you can (and should) edit the question =)

Comment: Perhaps you can give us an example of what you're trying to achieve? Some example strings that should (and shouldn't match)? I'm not even going to attempt to guess what you're trying to achieve with that regex!

Answer (score 1):

The following regex matches 0-3 whitespace characters.

```
\s{0,3}
```

The following regex matches strings with up to 3 whitespace characters.

```
^[^\s]+\s?[^\s]*\s?[^\s]*\s?[^\s]*$
```

Examples:

```
"ab" - (match)
"a b" - (match)
"a b c" - (match)
"a b c d" - (match)
"a b c d e" - (doesn't match)
"a b c d e f" - (doesn't match)
```

(Still waiting for examples from the questioner!)

Comment: where to place the above code in the expression: var pattern= /^(?=[^ ]* ?[^ ]*(?: [^ ]*)?$)(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?=[^']*'?[^']*$)[a-zA-Z '-]*$/;

Answer (score 1):

### Do you need a regex at all

If the sole purpose of what you want to do is to permit up to 3 spaces anywhere in a string - why not simply compare the length of the string before and after removing all spaces (or whiespace characters `\s` if relevant)? If the difference is more than 3 characters - it contains more than 3 spaces.

e.g.

```
var mainStr = "Hello Wor l d";

if(mainStr.replace(/ /g, '').length > (mainStr.length - 3)) {
    alert("matched");
}else{
    alert("not matched");
}
```

If your requirement is more specific - you need to clarify (edit the question), otherwise don't use regular expressions when they aren't necessary.

Comment: No i need to add condition to this expression: var pattern= /^(?=[^ ]* ?[^ ]*(?: [^ ]*)?$)(?=[^-]*-?[^-]*$)(?=[^']*'?[^']*$)[a-zA-Z '-]*$/;

Comment: @user2962526 *Why* do you need to add it *specifically to the regex*?

Comment: @user2962526 that's a none trivial regex to solve a trivial problem - as asked by others: why do you _need_ to solve it with a regex? Do you know what that regex does =) (from your comments it sounds likely you do not)? What is it supposed to be doing? And why are you adding it to all your comments - it's in the question.